# XML to CSV using XSLT with missing elements

Tags: .net, vb.net, csv, xslt-1.0

I need to convert XML into CSV using an XSLT (compatible with .NET framework). For the moment I came up with the following solution:

XML:

```
<items>
    <item>
        <col1>AAA1</col1>
        <col2>BBB1</col2>
        <col3>CCC1</col3>
        <col4>DDD1</col4>
        <col5>EEE1</col5>
    </item>
    <item>
        <col1>AAA2</col1>
        <col2>BBB2</col2>
        <col5>EEE2</col5>
    </item>
    <item>
        <col1>AAA3</col1>
        <col2>BBB3</col2>
        <col3>CCC3</col3>
        <col4>DDD3</col4>
        <col5>EEE3</col5>
    </item>
</items>
```

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:csv="csv:csv"
    xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common">

    <xsl:output encoding="utf-8" method="text"/>
    <xsl:variable name="delimiter" select="';'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="newline" select="'&#xa;'"/>

    <xsl:variable name="csv_header">
        <csv:columns xmlns:csv="csv:csv">
            <column>HDR1</column>
            <column>HDR2</column>
            <column>HDR3</column>
            <column>HDR4</column>
            <column>HDR5</column>
        </csv:columns>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="header" select="ext:node-set($csv_header)/*"/>

    <xsl:template name="print_value">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
            <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="gen-header">
        <xsl:for-each select="$header/child::*" xmlns:csv="csv:csv">
            <xsl:call-template name="print_value"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:value-of select="$newline"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="parse-node">
        <xsl:for-each select=".//child::*">
            <xsl:if test="count(*) = 0">
                <xsl:call-template name="print_value"/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="parse-data">
        <xsl:for-each select="*">
            <xsl:call-template name="parse-node"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$newline"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:call-template name="gen-header"/>
        <xsl:call-template name="parse-data"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Unfortunately, some tags can be missing in the input XML file (and I don't have the control over the input).

So the output CSV currently looks like this:

```
HDR1;HDR2;HDR3;HDR4;HDR5
AAA1;BBB1;CCC1;DDD1;EEE1
AAA2;BBB2;EEE2
AAA3;BBB3;CCC3;DDD3;EEE3
```

But what I need is to be able to produce the CSV like the following:

```
HDR1;HDR2;HDR3;HDR4;HDR5
AAA1;BBB1;CCC1;DDD1;EEE1
AAA2;BBB2;;;EEE2
AAA3;BBB3;CCC3;DDD3;EEE3
```

How to do that?

Comment: You seem to know in advance that there are (at most) 5 columns. Do you also know their names ( col1, col2, etc.)?

Comment: @michael.hor257k Yes, I know in advance the structure of the XML (maximum number of columns and their names). It should follow the header structure in the xslt but some columns can be missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the columns names, then you could do simply:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/items">
    <xsl:text>HDR1;HDR2;HDR3;HDR4;HDR5&#10;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each select="item">
        <xsl:value-of select="col1"/>
        <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="col2"/>
        <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="col3"/>
        <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="col4"/>
        <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="col5"/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Not a generic one but solves my problem. Is there a way to do it more generic?

Comment: I don't think you can make it "generic" when the input XML may not even have all the required columns.