# Transform XML with missing element values into wide CSV format through XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

How would you efficiently transform this XML document

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Document>
  <Person>
    <Entry>
      <Name>Height</Name>
      <Value>172</Value>
    </Entry>
    <Entry>
      <Name>Weight</Name>
      <Value>73</Value>
    </Entry>
  </Person>
  <Person>
    <Entry>
      <Name>Height</Name>
      <Value>180</Value>
    </Entry>
    <Entry>
      <Name>Weight</Name>
      <Value>70</Value>
    </Entry>
    <Entry>
      <Name>Age</Name>
      <Value>30</Value>
    </Entry>    
  </Person>
  <Person>
    <Entry>
      <Name>Height</Name>
      <Value>176</Value>
    </Entry>
    <Entry>
      <Name>Age</Name>
      <Value>25</Value>
    </Entry>    
  </Person>  
</Document>
```

into this CSV file?

```
"Height","Weight","Age"
"172","73",""
"180","70","30"
"176","","25"
```

It is different from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32329277/xml-to-csv-using-xslt-with-missing-elements) in which the missingness (or variation) is in elements, not in element values.

Comment: Are the column names - Height, Weight and Age - known in advance? And also, which version of XSLT?

Comment: Any XSLT version. And yes, column names are known in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" />

<xsl:template match="/Document">
    <xsl:text>"Height","Weight","Age"&#10;</xsl:text>  
    <xsl:for-each select="Person">
        <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="Entry[Name='Height']/Value"/>
        <xsl:text>","</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="Entry[Name='Weight']/Value"/>
        <xsl:text>","</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="Entry[Name='Age']/Value"/>
        <xsl:text>"&#10;</xsl:text>  
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```